# Woocommerce Shipping Calcuation (%) wrong

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

On my Woocommerce shop I have a percentage based shipping cost. The percentage is set to 5 ([fee percent="5"]) which returns a wrong calculation, but interestingly enough it seems to be the separator that is placed wrong (see attached example). 5% in the example is 14.5 GBP, but Woocommerce returns the calculation as 1.45.

Any suggestions?

THANKS[image: ![enter image description here]